# Docker Machine: Not working: Cert permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I'm trying from CloudSigma provider to create a docker machine and shows this error at the connect and execute "docker ps":

> could not read CA certificate "/root/.docker/machine/machines/default/ca.pem": open /root/.docker/machine/machines/default/ca.pem: permission denied

Any solution???

Thank you.